# Ошибка “Fatal error: Class '…' not found” в phpUnit

Tags: php, юнит-тесты, composer, phpunit, autoload

тестируемый класс, лежит в app\web:

```
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);
namespace app\web;

class Application
{
    private $config = [];

    public function __construct(array $config = null)
    {
        if ($config !== null) {
            $this->checkConfig($config);
            $this->config = $config;
        }
    }

    public function configure(array $config)
    {
        $this->checkConfig($config);
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function checkConfigure()
    {
        return !empty($this->config);
    }

    public function run()
    {
        if (empty($this->config)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function notFound()
    {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException();
    }
    public function sayHello()
    {
        echo 'Hello World!';
    }

    private function checkConfig($config)
    {
        if (!is_array($config)) {
            throw new \Exception("Config must be an array!");
        }
    }
}
```

Класс с тестами в tests\web:

```
<?php

namespace tests\web;

use app\web\Application;

class ApplicationTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testRunApplication(){
        $app = new Application(['param'=>'value']);
        $this->assertTrue($app->run());

        $wrongApp = new Application([]);
        $this->assertFalse($wrongApp->run());

        $this->assertEquals(true, $app->run());

        $this->markTestIncomplete('Incomplete');
    }
}
```

Собственно проблема в том, что при запуске phpunit возникает ошибка:

**Fatal error: Class 'app\web\Application' not found in C:\wamp64\www\unit_test_learning\tests\web\ApplicationTest.php on line 11**

Не нашел в сети решение. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.

*использовал composer, если это важно

Comment: а откуда и с какими настройками запускается тест?

Comment: Подправьте автолоадер. В автолоадер надо добавить директорию - где начинается неймспейс app . Это если там psr4 - что скорее всего с композером `$loader->setPsr4('app\\', __DIR__ . '/path/to/app');`

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр не помогло, ошибка осталась.(добавлял в vendor/composer/autoload_real.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне помогли в другом сервисе. Ошибка была в загрузчике.
Исправил на:

```
 "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
          "app\\web\\": "app/web/" ,
          "\\":""
        }
      }
```

Перелопатил кучу статей и документацию, но так и не понял, как формировать автозагрузчик в composer.

Буду очень признателен, если кто-то поможет это понять.